# Can I use PC controllers with my XBox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

Can we use cheap PC controllers with the XBox 360 by connecting it to the USB slot? PC controllers are much cheaper than Microsoft's.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but someone may land here looking for the inverse.  It is possible to use an Xbox 360 controller from a PC, but you have to buy a USB receiver.  I have my regular controllers working this way, as well as the Xbox 360 steering wheel.

Answer (score 4):

The controller has to be compatible.  You can't use just any USB controller.  An example of a controller that works on both the XBox 360 and the PC is [the MadCatz Xbox 360 FPS Pro](http://store.madcatz.com/platforms/xbox360/Mad-Catz-X360-FPS-Pro-Official-Wired-Xbox360-GamePad.html).

Comment: Link is invalid

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score -1):

The controller must be XInput and must meet the XBox requirements to work.

Comment: What requirements would those be?