# Using PC controllers with XInput on a 360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I own 2 pc controllers, 1 redgear pro wireless and 1 redgear pro wired. I was wondering if there was a way to connect them to my ol' xbox 360? I read that controllers that use XInput work in  [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18134/can-i-use-pc-controllers-with-my-xbox-360)  thread and I know that these use XInput. However when I connect them directly to the 360 they don't work at all. Is there any workaround or way for me to connect them to a 360? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://fccid.io/2AJ4F-RPSWG/User-Manual/Users-manual-3402923), you can switch between DirectInput and XInput modes by holding the Home button for ~5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, I've done that and the light indicators even show it's on XInput mode but they aren't recognised and the buttons don't do anything.

Answer (score -2):

While I have not personally tested third party PC controllers on this, I suspect a Brook Wingman XB would work with what you're trying to do as it's XInput.

Comment: This isn't really a helpful answer. Please rewrite it with some more factual detail rather than only putting assumptions.